# Sharing mounted EFS from Linux EC2 to Windows has terrible performance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012-r2, samba, amazon-efs

I've followed a large amount of advice in establishing an EFS share that can be accessed through windows.

The procedure is basically outlined here:

[Adding EFS to Windows Tutorial](https://erudinsky.com/2017/08/30/aws-efs-windows)

Following this, I added a large amount of dummy data (1.1 TB) as per the AWS recommendation on improving EFS performance. 
[AWS EFS Performance Recommendations](http://AWS%20EFS%20Performance%20Recommendations)

Unfortunately, no matter how much data I add, my network share hangs for a bit when being accessed through windows, which makes it basically unusable for my purposes.

**EDIT**

After more research, I've noticed similar posts that recommend a setting of 'nolock' on my nfs mount. However, some sites have indicated that NSF4 doesn't allow disabling the lock. Is there a workaround to this?